# Trying to create a ticket and tag from user attributes not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to take user data and make a separate ticket and tag from there. In my controller I have

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def create 
    user = User.new(user_params) 
    if user.save 
     ticket = Ticket.create(user_id: user.id, title: user.title)
     ticket.save
     Tag.new(tags: user.tags)
    else 
        render json: {errors: user.errors.full_messages}, status: 422
    end 
end
```

but that does not work. Also, in my TicketsController I have the ticket strong params as

```
def ticket_params 
        params.require(:user).permit(:user_id, :title) 
    end
```

which I think is where I'm going wrong, but have tried several different things and nothing works.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. "Not working" is unfortunely completely useless information (otherwise our jobs would be really easy). You need to tell us what the input is (the parameters in this case) the expected output and what the actual output or error message is. Its impossible for an outsider to know what you actually intended this code to do.

Comment: Its usually really helpful if you can describe what the code is supposed to do from a user story standpoint "When a user does X they should see X and Y should happen" instead of getting bogged down in what you think the solution is (ticket_params in this case is totally irrelevant). And please respond by editing your question to improve it so that is is answerable.